# Creating recursive function findValue() in linked list

Tags: python

Im trying to create a recursive function called findValue() that determines whether a given data value is in a linked list. The function returns True if the value is present and False otherwise. This is the implementation of the Node class:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self,initdata):
        self.data = initdata
        self.next = None

    def getData(self):
        return self.data

    def getNext(self):
        return self.next

    def setData(self,newdata):
        self.data = newdata

    def setNext(self,newnext):
        self.next = newnext
```

and this is the code that I have so far:

```
from Node import Node

def findValue(value, linkedList):
    if value == linkedList.getData():
        return True
    if linkedList == None:
        return False
    else:
        print("now:", linkedList.getData())
        print("next", linkedList.getNext())
        return findValue(value, linkedList.getNext())
```

I tried testing my code with these values:

```
n1 = Node(10); n2 = Node(20); n3 = Node(30); head = Node(40); n2.setNext(n1); 
n3.setNext(n2); head.setNext(n3)
```

I want my code to return False when the value given isn't in my linked list. However, when I try findValue(50, head) I get:

```
now: 40
next: <Node.Node object at 0x10c410ac8>
now: 30
next: <Node.Node object at 0x10bf3b710>
now: 20
next: <Node.Node object at 0x10de5b898>
now: 10
next: None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#34>", line 1, in <module>
    findValue(50, head)
  File "/Users/Shared/Homework3/hw3.py", line 29, in findValue
    return findValue(value, linkedList.getNext())
  File "/Users/Shared/Homework3/hw3.py", line 29, in findValue
    return findValue(value, linkedList.getNext())
  File "/Users/Shared/Homework3/hw3.py", line 29, in findValue
    return findValue(value, linkedList.getNext())
  [Previous line repeated 1 more time]
  File "/Users/Shared/Homework3/hw3.py", line 22, in findValue
    if value == linkedList.getData():
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'getData'
```

So towards the end, I see that the next value is None. Shouldn't None be the argument for the recursive call, therefore if linkedList == None: would be true, thus return False?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the outset, I want to say that I'm not sure this particular question belongs on CS StackExchange - we're more about math and theory than we are about coding (though we still code, I'm sure). I'd point you to using StackOverflow or some of the more programming-oriented StackExchanges for future questions.

With all that said, let's take a look at what's going on.

You have a Node class which has data and a next reference (the next reference being another Node).

You also have getters and setters for the Node class, good, good.

Now you seem to have some sort of problem with traversal of the LinkedList - your findValue() function seems to call getData on a NoneType object - which I'm going to assume is the equivalent of `null` in Java and other languages.

So, for your example, you know that 50 is not in the LinkedList at all. You call findValue and it recurses through your linkedList and then it mysteriously breaks...

Switch your if-statements, so the None check comes first. What if LinkedList is a NoneType object? Then checking getData() will fail because you're calling it on something that *doesn't* have that attribute/method - and you do do this because the getData check comes before the None check. I think this is the source of the problem.

But, in the words of Knuth - "Beware of bugs in the above code; I have only proved it correct, not tried it."

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

This might be fixed by ordering 4 lines differently.  In these lines:

```
    if value == linkedList.getData():
        return True
    if linkedList == None:
        return False
```

When your code gets here with `linkedList == None` it tries to find `.getData()` in an empty object BEFORE checking if the object is empty and returning false.  Reorder these and you should be good to go:

```
    if linkedList == None:
        return False
    if value == linkedList.getData():
        return True
```